IBM Cognos Jupyter Notebooks installation error
I am trying to install IBM Cognos Jupyter Notebooks. Unfortunatly, when running install.bat (like described in the offical documentation https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cognos-analytics/12.0.0?topic=server-installing-jupyter-notebook-microsoft-windows-10) I get the following error:
docker: invalid reference format. One of the two docker containers that should be running is running correctly (ca_jupyter_viewer).
When I try to build.bat the other one (ca_jupyter_hub) I get this error:
ERROR [10/13] RUN if [ -s additional_pip_packages.txt ]; then         pip install --user -r additional_pip_pa  0.8s
0.467 Collecting pixiedust==1.1.17
0.632   Downloading pixiedust-1.1.17.tar.gz (197 kB)
0.747     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     cwd: /tmp/pip-install-v42jsx1e/pixiedust_ca3474f6ec73405d987edf8f1e5a2d47/
0.747     Complete output (3 lines):
0.747     Traceback (most recent call last):
0.747       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
0.747     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'setuptools'
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c if [ -s additional_pip_packages.txt ]; then         pip install --user -r additional_pip_packages.txt;     fi  && rm additional_pip_packages.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

I already tried reinstalling Docker Desktop v27.2.0, made sure that Linux containers are used and reinstalling the IBM Cognos Jupyter Notebooks itself.
